# How do I specify the string method count?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a function that takes a string as a parameter, and whether or not the string contains the letter 'ion' at the end determines the output.

For example, if I input the string 'accordionist', I should then get the output of 'accordionist' because although it contains 'ion', it is not at the end of the string.

However, if I input the string 'congratulation', I want to then change the 'ion' to an 'e' because 'ion' is at the end of the word.

So far I have :

```
def wordSwap(x):

    if x.count('ion') == 1:
        return x.replace('ion','e')
    else:
        return x
```

```
>>> wordSwap('congratulation')
'congratulate'
```

This works well, but when I use a string such as:

```
>>> wordSwap('accordionist')
```

I get

```
'accordeist'
```

How do I specify that I only want to change the 'ion' to an 'e' only if it is at the end of the string?

Comment: The answers provided are correct, but as a side note for your future reference, `if 'ion' in x` is more pythonic and readable than `if x.count('ion') == 1`.

Comment: One example where this won’t work: “invention” and “invent”. Unfortunately grammar is rarely so regular ;)

Comment: @JamesScholes It might be more Pythonic and readable, but it has completely different meaning!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Clbuttic!

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> def wordswap(x):
...    return re.sub("ion$", "e", x)
...
>>> wordswap("accordionist")
'accordionist'
>>> wordswap("congratulation")
'congratulate'
```

`$` is the "end of string" anchor (it only matches at the end of the string).

Comment: Beat me to it by few seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
def wordSwap(x):
    if x.endswith('ion'):
        return x[-3:] + 'e'
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm embarrassed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there a word that could possibly end with ionion? :) however you could just add one more if statement to check that like Pavel showed you

Comment: @John The original version of this answer used the `replace` function. My edit prompted Pavel to use the same slice based code that is found in my answer. Here's a word that would be handled incorrectly: ionisation. I'm not sure what Pavel showed me. What are you referring to?

Comment: @JohnBrown: ionization, unionization, fictionization, professionalization and others all fail with my initial version.